# Windows 10 WebDav issue freezes/crashes/stalls with files over 50 MB

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, freeze, nas, webdav

Recently, my company bought a Synology DS1019+ NAS and I've moved my colleagues to it so they can work from home. I used WebDAV to map the shared folder (\naspath@SSL@5006\folder).
I can upload files without problem but if any file is over 50 MB I can't run or copy it back to my computer. I found that editing FileSizeLimitInBytes attribute for the WebClient fixes this, however it causes file explorer to hang for a long time even if I only open a context menu on that file. When I return the file size limit back to default it works fine but then I can't do anything with the file.

Is there a registry tweak or something to fix this? Maybe a way to force WebClient to process files in chunks acceptable to it? I will need that increased file size limit and I would like to enable others to download larger files through the file explorer as most of them are terrible with technology.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did your NAS come with a software suite, such as Drive, MailPlus and the like? Those apps are usually taylored for the hardware and work rather well, but can conflict with other software.

Comment: It came with File Station but I installed several other packages. Haven't configured them all yet.

Comment: I should mention that WinSCP works just fine with any files. Windows WebClient occasionally says the file doesn't exist among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
    
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters]
    
    "BasicAuthLevel"=dword:00000002
    
    
"FileSizeLimitInBytes"=dword:ffffffff
```

Basic Auth set to 2 improves connectivity. 1 is the default.

File size limit is set to 50mb by default in windows for Webdav. I have set it to 4gb. Works for me.